# how to add MongoOptions in MongoClient in casbah mongo scala driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

i want to add mongoOptions to MongoClient basically i want  to add ConnectionPerHost value its default is 10 i want to increase it to 20
but i am getting errors in the code i have tried with two different ways

```
val SERVER:ServerAddress = {

val hostName=config.getString("db.hostname")

val port=config.getString("db.port").toInt
        new ServerAddress(hostName,port)
          }
val DATABASE:String   = config.getString("db.dbname")
```

**method 1**

```
val options=MongoClientOptions.apply( connectionsPerHost=20 )
val connectionMongo = MongoConnection(SERVER).addOption(options.getConnectionsPerHost)//returning Unit instead of MongoClient 
val collectionMongo = connectionMongo(DATABASE)("testdb")
```

getting error on last line   `Unit does not take parameters`

**method 2**

```
val mongoOption=MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .connectionsPerHost(20)
                .build();
```

getting error on `MongoClientOptions.builder()` line

```
value builder is not a member of object com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClientOptions

-
```

i want to set connectionsPerHost value to 20 please help what is the right way to do this

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load();
val hostName = config.getString("db.hostname")
val port = config.getInt("db.port")

val server = new ServerAddress(hostName, port)
val database = config.getString("db.dbname")

val options = MongoClientOptions(connectionsPerHost = 20)
val connectionMongo = MongoClient(server, options) 
val collectionMongo = connectionMongo(database)("testdb")
```

Note that [MongoConnection is deprecated](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/3.1/scaladoc/#package).